# How can I check if page has noindex?

Tags: php, noindex

My intention is to fetch the link with PHP and maybe with [Simple PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) (or something similar) parse the content and look for H1-H6 tags. But prior to that I would need to find out if the page is being indexed at all.

Other than parsing the content and searching for `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` or similar, is there a way I could check if a page is set to noindex also in robots.txt?

Comment: Why don't you just load and parse robots.txt to see if the page is set to noindex?

Comment: up voted for actually caring unlike most scrappers.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways pages specify noindex: via a meta HTML tag in the  section (as you noted), or via HTTP header in the response.

On top of that, there are two ways to specify noindex: one is "noindex", and the other is "none" (which is the equivalent of "noindex, nofollow").

HTML tags can target several crawlers, and could look like this:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
```

or

```
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex" />
```

or

```
<meta name="AdsBot-Google" content="noindex" />
```

or others.

Google has a [pretty good writeup here](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag?hl=en)

So the way to check for noindex is to do both:

1. Check for an X-Robots-Tag containing "noindex" or "none" in the HTTP responses (try curl -I https://www.example.com to see what they look like)
2. Get the HTML and scan meta tags in  for "noindex" or "none" in the content attribute